# Filter files in Visual Studio Code Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, filtering

How to dynamically filter all the files seen in the Visual Studio Code File Explorer?

The Focusing and hitting Ctrl+F does not always work, is confusing with Find in files and folders and does not effectively filter (or if it filters, the files are not all visible in the list as in the following image).

I **don't** search a *static* filter, but a dynamic way to, by eg. see all the .ts files in my project, already expanded as Visual Studio does:

[image]